# What is the meaning of the phrase "Land Sakes"?

Tags: meaning, phrases, minced-oaths

In a children's story I was reading the other day, one of the characters said

> "Land Sakes"

...from the context of the story, it must be to indicate they are surprised?

It was completely foreign to me and I just generally wanted to know more about it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a euphemism for "Lord Sakes", which is itself a non-grammatical corruption of "for the Lord's sake!"

It can be pretty amusing to observe the lengths to which people will go to avoid blasphemy, while still expressing their strong feelings on a subject...

Comment: Similarly 'lawks' - both are a bit dated but a staple of 19C fiction.

Comment: I've never quite understood why expressing the same feeling, but using different sounds was avoiding blasphemy.  Is it really the noises we make that make the difference, and motives are immaterial?

Comment: @thursdaygeek - The motives of believers are a deep, dark mystery to me - [Pascal's Wager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_wager) being the classic example.  If the deity you believe in (or decide to _pretend_ to believe in) is actually omnipotent, can't S/He see your motives?  And if not... then what's the point?

Comment: @MT_head - probably to avoid upsetting other people especially, in times pasts, more religous ones. Same reason you say oh-flip instead oh-fuck in front of other people's children

Comment: @Martin - I understand the motive for euphemism in people who habitually use stronger language - I also censor myself (usually successfully!) around kids and polite company. But "land sakes!" and "lawks!" are/were typically used by people who _never_ said anything stronger... so again, the psychology befuddles me.  If you believe that blasphemy is wrong and God will punish you for it, what's the motivation for skirting blasphemy as closely as possible?  To me, it's a slightly different case than "oh flip"; I suspect that you personally don't believe you'd go to Hell for saying "oh fuck?"

Comment: @MT_Head - possibly the concern is what the rest of the village, especially the 17C guys with buckles on the hats, might think if you say God. You only have to look at how their descendants react to mild language on TV. Also God is known for being a bit of a stickler for the rules. If you ask his chosen people, saying God is bad but saying YHVH is Ok.

Comment: Actually it has not only to do with God, but with a lot with protecting children from using strong words they don't understand. A child can unwittingly get into a lot of trouble with unknowns without having any idea how they got there if they use abusive language. So this is very much like how we protect children in all sorts of ways from themselves and others, until they can judge better for themselves.

Answer (score 0):

I'd add that my grandmother used the term "land sakes," but only because she'd no doubt learned it as a child and never paused to wonder at its origin. So "religious people" can easily learn to use such replacement terms without ever perceiving the deeper meaning or intent of what they're saying.

Comment: If even the people using the term don't understand the "deeper meaning or intent" of the phrase, does it really even exist? I think at a certain point lots of expletives tend to lose their original meaning and become merely expletives with no deeper intent implied on the part of the speaker.